Issue with connecting to MQTT client running on Windows PC from Raspberry Pi
I'm in the mechanical field and have limited experience with any network protocol. For an autonomous robot project, I am communicating between a base station Windows PC and a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.
I've been doing this by hosting a mosquitto MQTT broker on the Windows PC, and selectively subscribing/publishing to topics to exchange commands and telemetry using Python.
I create a local network using a USB wifi dongle on the PC, and connect both devices to this network. Their IPs on this network remain constant.
This has been working perfectly for around a month, however has suddenly stopped working. I'm unable to connect to the broker from the Pi, and am unable to ssh into the Pi from the PC. I am also unable to ping the Pi - I don't get any response.
In testing this I am running the Pi side of the scripts in a fresh, up-to-date install of the rasbian OS. These problems have been reproduced on a Raspberry Pi 4 and Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.
The PC-side implementation of the MQTT handler:
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

HOST_NAME =  "localhost"

class Client:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print("[INFO] Initialising Comms.")
        self.client = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2)
        
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message    
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        
        self.client.connect(HOST_NAME, 1883, 60)
        self.client.subscribe("RobotStatus")
        self.client.subscribe("RobotCommand")
        
        self.client.loop_start()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc, prop):
        print("[INFO] Connection with the client was a " + str(rc) + ".")

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        print("[TOPIC]:", msg.topic, msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))

    def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        print("[INFO] MQTT client disconnected.")
        client.loop_stop()
        
    def sendMessage(self, topic, message, qos):
        self.client.publish(topic, message, qos)
    

The Pi-side implementation of the MQTT handler, implemented in a Python3.11 venv:
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

from robot import Robot

HOST_NAME = "192.168.137.1" # USB hub IP

class Client:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2)
        
        self.robot = Robot()
        
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        
        self.client.connect(HOST_NAME, 1883, 60)
        self.client.subscribe("RobotCommand")
        self.client.subscribe("RobotPose")
        self.client.subscribe("RobotStatus")
        self.client
        print("[INFO] Communication with base initialised.")
        
        self.client.loop_start()
        
    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc, prop):
        print("[INFO] Connection with base was a " + str(rc) + ".")
        self.robot.sendMessage("[INFO] Robot connection with base was a " + str(rc) + ".")

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        if (msg.topic == "RobotCommand"):
            self.robot.updateCommand(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
        elif (msg.topic == "RobotPose"):
            self.robot.updatePose(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
        print("Message On Status: " + msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
        
    def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        print("[INFO] Client disconnected")
        
    def getRobot(self):
        return self.robot

I run the MQTT broker from a terminal with a custom .conf file that contains:
allow_anonymous true 
listener 1883 0.0.0.0

I have confirmed that when this is running, that the server is listening on port 1883:
PS C:\Users\nshep> netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1883           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

The specific error I receive upon trying to connect from the Pi varies, they have included:
"socket.timeout: timed out"
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
"OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host"
The IP address I am using to attempt to connect to the PC Broker from the Pi:
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::88d7:fcda:c3ec:fda5%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1 <- have been using this address
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:8003:edc2:1b01:71e2:80d6:5b43:37a0
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2001:8003:edc2:1b01:2890:3f20:9c57:1698
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4ece:dc7c:4278:cea5%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.24
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::be30:d9ff:fef6:fe42%15
                                       192.168.0.1

When the Pi first connects to the network, prior to running any scripts, it responds to a ping and successfully allows an SSH connection:
PS C:\Users\nshep> ping 192.168.137.252

Pinging 192.168.137.252 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.137.252: bytes=32 time=308ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.252: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.252: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.252: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.252:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 308ms, Average = 81ms

Calling arp -a  on the Pi prior to running any scripts yields:
~ $ arp -a 
LAPTOP-KT5C8T77.mshome.net (192.168.137.1) at 26:5a:fc:59:80:05 [ether] on wlan0

AFTER the Pi client has failed to connect and thrown errors, it no longer responds to the ping and times out, despite showing as still connected to the network on both the Pi and the PC:
PS C:\Users\nshep> ping 192.168.137.252                                                                                                                                                                                                         Pinging 192.168.137.252 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.252:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
PS C:\Users\nshep> ssh nshep@192.168.137.252
ssh: connect to host 192.168.137.252 port 22: Connection timed out

I have noticed that after running the program on the Pi, it loses the ability to detect new networks if it is disconnected from the local network; I have to restart it in order to have the option to select a network again. In this state, calling arp -a on the Pi yields:
? (192.168.137.1) at <incomplete> on wlan0

Attempting to ping the PC from the Pi in this state yields:
~ $ ping 192.168.137.1
PING 192.168.137.1 (192.168.137.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.137.252 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

It seems the script failing seems to break something; a restart is needed to fix the Pi's ability to see or connect to networks.
I have tried disabling my network firewalls; this had no effect on the problem. The only thing I can identify that has changed since things were working was a batch of Windows updates.
I have tried running the Pi off different power sources; this had no effect on the problem.
I have tried running the devices on multiple different networks and have triple-checked the IPs I pass to the Pi to direct it to the MQTT broker.
I have confirmed the broker is functioning properly locally on the PC; messages publish and can be read from subscribed topics as expected.
I have tried instead hosting the MQTT broker on the Pi; I encountered similar issues when trying to connect to the broker from the PC as when I attempted to SSH into the Pi.
The only obvious thing I haven't tried is using a different PC as the base station; I don't currently have access to one.

This feels more like a question for SuperUser as it very much feels like it's a network problem, nothing to do with programming or MQTT. You imply that the Windows machine is creating the WiFi network, I would check that it's not enabled things like device separation.
